# For the Hazelcast IMDG open source edition, is there a limit on the number of members/nodes allowed within a hazelcast cluster?

Tags: hazelcast

For the open source Hazelcast IMDG version/edition, is there a limit on the number of members/nodes allowed within a hazelcast cluster?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no limit on the number of members allowed.